# How to create nested php objects

Tags: php, object

I am trying to create a php object that has the following layer.

```
$obj->property->name;
$obj->property->title;
$obj->property->id;
$obj->property->height;
```

It give me '`Trying to get property of non-object`' error

My object

```
$obj = [
   'property' => [
       'name' => 'Rick',
       'title' => 'manager',
       'id' => '123',
       'height' => '5.6'
   ]
];

 $obj = = (object)$obj;
```

I am not sure the correct syntax to produce `$obj->property->name;`Can anyone help me out? My brain is fired....Thanks!

Comment: `$obj` is declared as an array, you could just cast `(object)` on declaration

Comment: this should be `$obj->property['name'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cast to `object` also `property`:

```
$obj = [
   'property' => [
       'name' => 'Rick',
       'title' => 'manager',
       'id' => '123',
       'height' => '5.6'
   ]
];

$object = (object)$obj;
$object->property = (object)$object->property;
```

Result:

```
var_dump($object->property->id); // string(3) "123"
var_dump($object->property->name); // string(4) "Rick"
// etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array inside the `property object` you can not use like that

```
$obj->property->name;
```

**This should be:**

```
$obj->property['name'];
```

**Example:**

```
$yourArr = array('property'=>array(
       'name' => 'Rick',
       'title' => 'manager',
       'id' => '123',
       'height' => '5.6'
   ));

$yourObj = (object) $yourArr;
echo $yourObj->property['name']; // Rick
```